# Angular 6/7 service worker can't load lazy loaded module after update, unexpected token <

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading, service-worker

In my current angular project, there seems to be an issue with lazy loaded modules in the service worker. But I can't see whats wrong with it. Even after updating or deleting the service worker, on the next update the issue appears again.

5.xxx.js

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

main.xxx.js

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Loading chunk 5 failed.
>   (missing: https://myUrl.com/5.c4a41f82a61c11f9205b.js)
>   Error: Loading chunk 5 failed.

**Setup**

My routes are configured as follows, modules with preloadstrategy work properly when updating.

```js
const routes: Route[] = [
  { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'projects', loadChildren: '../modules/projects/projects.module#ProjectsModule', data: {preload: true} },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: '../modules/admin/admin.module#AdminModule',
    canLoad: [AdminGuardService]
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

The 5.xxx.js is for sure the admin.module compilation.
The preload strategy is defined as

```js
import { PreloadingStrategy, Route } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

export class AppPreloadStrategy implements 
PreloadingStrategy {
  preload(route: Route, load: Function): Observable<any> {
    return route.data && route.data.preload ? load() : of(null);
  }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that it isn't preload related but service worker related.

My service worker is (simplified) configured as

```json
{
  "name": "modules",
  "installMode": "lazy",
  "updateMode": "prefetch",
  "resources": {
    "files": [
      "/?.*.js",
      "/??.*.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

as an assetGroup. Also there is the assetGroup app with `index.html`, `main.*.js` etc having *installMode* `prefetch`.

Thanks for your help, cheers!

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out? I am having the same issue.

Comment: No not really. This issue appeared with Angular 6 and before. Updating to 7 seems to work fine, but I don't know where the issue is exactly coming from.

Comment: do you mean updating to 7 solved this issue for you?

Comment: This issue does not appear anymore when I deploy a new build, I think. But there seems to be some troubles so that the service worker does not update properly, they just serve an old state but without any errors.